# How to return Kotlin Flow as non-streaming JSON data using Content-Type: application/json in Spring Framework 6?

Tags: json, spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-flow

Controller method interface:

```kotlin
@RequestMapping(
        method = [RequestMethod.GET],
        value = ["/list"],
        produces = ["application/json"]
)
suspend fun list(): ResponseEntity<Flow<MyClass>>
```

Controller method implementation:

```kotlin
override suspend fun list(): ResponseEntity<Flow<MyClass>> {
    val list: List<MyClass> = service.getMyClass()
    val flow = flow { emitAll(list.asFlow()) }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(flow)
}
```

Before upgrading to Spring Boot 3 (Spring 6) this endpoint worked well as non-streaming endpoint.

After upgrade, it produces an error:

```
Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Array
```

I found this page:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-6.x

Here is the line:

```
Spring WebFlux

Flux return values for non-streaming media types (no longer collected to List before written).
```

So I understand that new version of Spring tries to stream my data and it does not matter that I have `Content-Type: application/json`.

The question is: how can I return old behavior?

My frontend requires it at the moment.

I see that this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61146874/22210497 - describes old behavior.

Now this code is gone from Spring codebase...

Probably after thoughts in this issue - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28398

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So probably I managed it to work by taking code from Spring 5 version:

```
class CustomJackson2JsonEncoder(mapper: ObjectMapper) : Jackson2JsonEncoder(mapper, *arrayOf()) {

    override fun encode(
        inputStream: Publisher<*>,
        bufferFactory: DataBufferFactory,
        elementType: ResolvableType,
        mimeType: MimeType?,
        hints: MutableMap<String, *>?
    ): Flux<DataBuffer> {
        if (inputStream is Mono || getStreamingMediaTypeSeparator(mimeType) != null) {
            return super.encode(inputStream, bufferFactory, elementType, mimeType, hints)
        }
        val listType = ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(List::class.java, elementType)
        return Flux
            .from(inputStream)
            .collectList()
            .map { encodeValue(it, bufferFactory, listType, mimeType, hints) }
            .flux()
    }

}

@Configuration
class WebFluxConfig(private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper) : WebFluxConfigurer {

    override fun configureHttpMessageCodecs(configurer: ServerCodecConfigurer) {
        configurer
            .defaultCodecs()
            .jackson2JsonEncoder(CustomJackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper))
    }

}
```

Firstly, this code is checking if we have `Mono` or streaming media type.

If yes, then it calls `encode` method of super class.

If no, then it collects `Flux` to `List` before writing.

Not sure if it is correct and where can be some caveats, but it works...